# How to unfreeze Xcode simulate location?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added my own Gxp file and all worked well on my iPhone. But now my iPhone map an google maps are stuck on that gpx file location. I have cleaned, restarted Xcode and even deleted my gpx file and restarted Xcode. My phone and Xcode won't let me see my real location on my phone even when unhooked from my computer.

Anyone know how to clear this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to go into the schema and change it to not use simulation. Then delete the file .gpx file from my computer. Then clean the app in xcode. Then delete the app from my iPHone.

Then turn it all back on.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to fix this by rebooting the phone (and vowing not to touch the simulate location settings again).